# How to apply clean architecture to embedded program?

Tags: c++, embedded, clean-architecture

Simply put, my question is how to achieve chip independence on a program that runs on an embedded OS.

I am writing a simple program in C++ that runs on an embedded OS (embed OS but it does not really matter in this question).
The embedded OS provides APIs to send and receive control information and data bidirectionally., e.g., `getc()` and `putc()` to receive and send a character.

Now the microcomputer is connected to a chip that is capable of running some commands (like making REST API calls or getting device location with GPS) by sending strings specified by the chip vendor using the API mentioned above.

What I want to do is to abstract the logic of executing commands in the chip so that the chip is easily replaceable with other chips with different command specifications when necessary.

So ideally I want to define an abstract class `CommandRunner` which has unimplemented methods for interacting with a chip. 
Then I can extend the class to make a concrete class which contains all the detail for running commands on a specific chip (as show below).

The problem I am facing is we don't know when we can receive the result of a command and in what order since there is only one port for getting the result (`out` in the example below). However we know which result corresponds to which command from the first few words of the result.
Thus currently I can only run commands but am not able to get results in an elegant way. Am I doing wrong?

```cpp
class VendorACommandRunner: CommandRunner {
  public:
  VendorACommandRunner(Serial *in, Serial *out) {
    // some initialization
  }
  Location fetchCurrentLocation() {
    in->printf("GETLOC\n"); // vendor specific command
  }
  HTTPResponse httpGet(string url) {
    in->printf("GET " + url);
  }
  ...
}
```

Comment: To be honest, I don't really see where your problem is. As you return a result directly from the function, you have created a *synchronous* interface. You cannot return until having received a response -> you cannot continue until having received a response -> you cannot send another request until having received a response. Can there be other, independent data coming in via result channel? Or do you have a multi-threaded setup with more than one thread using the same command runner?

Comment: @Aconcagua Sorry for the confusion. I don't stick to synchronous interface. As long as a function call returns its corresponding result synchronously or asynchronously, it is okay. Also there may be a timer that calls a functions at some interval, so yes I have multi-threaded setup.

Comment: OK, then at very first, you'll need to synchronise your interface properly. What, if a second thread interrupts the first oen right in the middle when printing the command? You could end up in getting something like `GETGETLOC\nLOC\n` on the outgoing serial interface. Have a look at [std::mutex](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/mutex) for that purpose. Then you need to somehow collect responses and dispatch them to the function calls. Maybe a separate reader thread listening on out.

Comment: @Aconcagua Okay i see. I don't have much experience in multi-threading programs in C++ but how do you dispatch a response to a correct function call?

Comment: A common way to let multiple threads access a single resource (like a hardware device) is to use queues. The requests from the threads are added into a single (protected) queue, the device driver extracts one request at a time from the queue and processes it, and then "sends" the reply back to the thread that created the request (for example through a callback function or similar).

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude I see! That makes things much simpler!

Comment: Simplest way to synchronise, even getting along without queue, is just leaving the mutex locked until response for previous request is received. So next thread simply cannot send a new request until previous response has been returned to previous caller...

Comment: A queue is more flexible, though, allows to send out next request already while previous one is still processed, so this can save some time. It can get a problem, though, if the target device possibly might not send back responses in the same order as requests were received (maybe multi-threaded, too, and processing times for different requests differ). *Then* you'd need a more sophisticated algorithm to assign responses to appropriate requester.

Comment: @Aconcagua I am thinking about making a simple REPL to interact with the chip with several commands. One command starts a timer to take logs from a sensor regularly at some interval. Meanwhile I want to run different commands. Is this possible to implement with synchronous approach?

Comment: Well, sure it is possible. However, you need to make sure that you synchronise the loop and the timer events appropriately. And at this point, you have numerous options. First question now would be if the device you want to communicate with is able at all to receive another request while still processing previous one. If not, then just go with the most simple solution I mentioned above...

Comment: Oh, one important issue: How are the timer events created? If e. g. by interrupt or OS signal, you cannot use a `std::mutex` to synchronise, as preemption mechanism differs to the one between two threads with equal rights!

Comment: Excuse me, but I don't really understand what you mean by "synchronise the loop and the timer events".
The device I want to communicate with is able to receive other requests while processing previous one.

Comment: You need to prevent that both the loop and the timer event try to access the single resource concurrently. Imagine the event and the loop run on different cores, and both write at the same time to the single serial device. That might lead to the two outputs getting interleaved or even some characters getting lost entirely. Even if the events are generated at the same core than the loop runs on, one thread might preempt the other one right in the middle when writing to the serial device, which again would produce interleaved output. Remember the `GETGETLOC\nLOC\n` example?

Comment: By the way, I use RTOS timer from mbed (https://os.mbed.com/handbook/RTOS#rtos-timer).

Comment: @Aconcagua > Remember the GETGETLOC\nLOC\n example?
Oh~ I see!

Comment: OK, that was *very* important information! From the link you posted: *'Timers are handled in the thread `osTimerThread`. Callback functions run under control of this thread and may use CMSIS-RTOS API calls.'* That would allow to use `std::mutex` or some RTOS-equivalent, and we can forget about signals or interrupts...

Comment: As you are pretty inexperienced, I propose you try at very first with the most simple approach possible: `class VACR { std::mutex m_mutex; public: L fetchCL() { std::lock_guard g(m_mutex); in->printf(...); /* wait for response */ out->read(...); /* process information */ return someLocation; }`

Comment: Thanks for the code snippet :) Yeah I think I will go with the simplest approach.
Even though the device can receive multiple messages while processing the previous one, it is complicated to assign a response to a correct function call.

Comment: You'd need to add the same lock guard to any other function, too. The lock guard gets destroyed automatically when leaving scope (i. e. the function returns) and unlocks the mutex again. This way, you can only send one single request at a time. Any other thread trying to send a request will have to wait until the mutex gets unlocked again. So dispatching is most simple: any response can only belong to the one and only request that has been sent...

Comment: So in this approach, if the timer runs a command that takes a while, then if I type another command on REPL it has to wait for the command run by timer to get a response, right?

Comment: To be precise: It has to wait until the timer received its response before it can send a request at all – and vice versa, by the way.

Comment: Yes :) Okay, I think everything is clear :) You made my day, thank you so much!